# Which is more efficient way to monitor progress of a long running code? print on screen or log to a text file?

Tags: java, python, progress

I have a java code that as part of the code it handles a very big matrix (1 million by 4 million) and it takes several hours to run, before it crashes!

I would like to monitor the progress of the code, so know when it runs out of memory and crashes what percentage of matrix was already processes.

I am thinking of adding a command to print on screen a counter (relative to the main operation loop) every 1000 iteration. or logging the counter in a text file.

Is this a good idea? Or will it slow down my already-slow code even further? After all I am adding a condition verification check (to check 1000th iteration) and file-write operation.

Any standard solution in java?

If there is no standard method or function for monitoring the progress, which would be more efficient, writing my own log to a file or printing on screen?

Bonus question: what about in Python? Any internal or standard library for this purspose?

thanks

Comment: This is extremely broad/vague. Basic logging is not very time or processor-intensive. Try and find out.

Answer (score 1):

Without having any context about what this code *does*, my advice would be that you could place an `if` condition check for every 1000<sup>th</sup> iteration, then does something (*print statement, calculation, output to log, check or what have you*). This `if` condition's affect on performance is extremely negligible, unless inside the body of the `if` condition performs some sort of *expensive calculation* (*modulus expression is **not** an expensive calculation for computers!*).

Python code:

```
for i in range(100000):  # Loop symbolizing your code.
    if i%1000 == 0:  # Every 1000th iteration do something.
         print "Progress"  # Do something.
```

That being said unless you're going to be staring at **stdout** for a few hours in real time; or scrolling though the (*what could be very large*) stdout log this does not seem like the most efficient idea. I would recommend you write out an error report for this program (*function*?) while collecting metadata during it's run-time to put in said report, and would propose unit-testing if you aren't already.